# AngularJS2 adding headers to http post doesn't work

Tags: http, angular, cors

I'm trying to add headers to my `http` post request as shown below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable() 
export class UserService extends ServiceBase {

    apiUrl: string; 
    private contentHeaders = new Headers();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
        this.apiUrl = appConfig.apiBaseUrl + '/users';
    }

    login(user: User) {
        this.contentHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        this.contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(
            this.apiUrl+'/sign_in', 
        JSON.stringify({user: user}),
            {headers: this.contentHeaders}
        );
    }
 }
```

Headers shown in Chrome DevTools:

`OPTIONS /api/v1/users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
Host: offers2win.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-credentials, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/?
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8`

But these headers are not seen in the Chrome dev tool, network panel. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(username: any, password: any) {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ "email" : username, "password" : password });
    let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(APIUrl+"/login", body, options).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: Still its the same. `Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type` :(

Comment: The server (that the POST request is sent to) needs to include the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header (etc) in its response. Putting them in your request from the client has no effect.

This is because it is up to the server to specify that it accepts cross-origin requests (and that it permits the Content-Type request header, and so on) – the client cannot decide for itself that a given server should allow CORS.

Comment: I have installed CORS extension in Chrome. Still it's not working.

Comment: I could make it work using post man, by adding two headers, `Content-Type` & `Accept`